# Machine learning algorithm for numeric/continuous n-dimensional data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm trying to find an algorithm that can take training inputs like such:

{1.1, 2.3, 3.5} -> "foo"
{4.7, 5.9, 6.1} -> "bar"

Where the first part is the data, and the second part is a category label I assign myself. The idea is that when I enter a new data point, it should be able to guess the correct label.

I've implemented Naive Bayes (although I have only tested it so far with the usual {red, round} -> "apple" thing), but I'm starting to think that discretization of the numeric data into boolean (statistical) events is not going to particularly easy or likely to produce good results (correct me if I'm wrong!). The thing I like about it (naive bayes) is that it's very simple and it is actually likely that down the line I WILL have data that fit's well into events.

So my question is, can you name some machine learning algorithms that can use numeric data directly? Or, alternatively, how can I effectively discretize floating point data into events (for use in, e.g. Naive Bayes)?

Other information: I've also implemented k-means for this project (The centroids it outputs are actually currently the source of the data), but what I'm interested in here is not simple clustering, but attaching intelligent labels/categories to data and teaching these labels to a machine.

Comment: [This post](http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/107702/2-ways-of-using-Naive-Bayes-classification-for-numeric-attributes) may help.

Comment: That was a great article! I'm thinking now that my best option will be to apply k-means to the training data, and create k attributes/events; 1 for each cluster. Essentially, when I pass in a new data point into my naive bayes implementation, it will calculate the probability (using the mean and standard deviation of the given cluster) that the data point belongs to a given cluster. I'd post this as a solution, but I'm still interested in whether there's an algorithm that's made specifically for continuous/numeric data, rather than categorical data.